# Does $f^{(n)} = 0$ imply that complex $f$ is a polynomial?

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

Let $f$ be a complex function with the property that $f^{(n)} = 0$.  Does this imply that $f$ is a polynomial?  If so, why?

Upon thinking about this problem myself, I can easily observe that every $n$ degree polynomial satisfies $f^{(n+1)} = 0$.  Still, this doesn't show that some non-polynomial function couldn't also have this property.

Comment: Have you done Taylor series yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Can you do the case $n=1$?  Induct on $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Consider that there is one unique solution to the differential equation $y^{(n)}(x) = 0$ where $y^{(j)}(0) = c_j\cdot (j-1)!$ for $0< j<n$ and $y(0) = c_0$.

This solution is the polynomial $y = c_{n-1}x^{n-1} + c_{n-2}x^{n-2} + \cdots + c_1x+ c_0$.